# Eclipse-CDT: How do I handle permission denied errors opening sockets?

Tags: c++, linux, debugging, eclipse-cdt, sudo

My program opens a socket on port 80, but if I don't run it as root (with sudo) then it fails to open the socket with a permission error.

This means my application doesn't work when I launch it in the debugger.

So:

1. Can I tell Eclipse-CDT somehow to launch the app using sudo?
2. Or, can I somehow enable my program to have permission to open port 80?

thx

- Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For debugging purposes, I'd pass `--port 8080` as an argument, or use some other configuration method, and open on 8080. No need for root permissions then.